# Create a matrix with dimension [N,D] from tensor with dimension [N]

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a tensor with dimension N and I would like to replicate it to  create a tensor with dimension NxD being each column the initial vector.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want first to expand/reshape your tensor to a `N x 1` shape, before tiling it `D` times in the 2nd dimension:

```python
tensor_N_x_1 = tf.expand_dims(tensor, 1)     # Expand by adding a dim in position 1
tensor_N_x_D = tf.tile(tensor_N_x_1, [1, D]) # Tile 1 time in the 1st dim, D times in the 2nd
```

Documentation:

- [tf.expand_dims](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims)
- [tf.tile](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tile)